# PDO mysql Update error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I seem to have an error I don't really understand. The process works fine, the connection to database is fine, but for some reason it doesn't update. There are no visible errors for me, or that `php` recognizes. Here is the code: (note that the last missing) on class I know about, and that happened when I copy pasted it, it's fine in the code

```
    public function change_password($user, $pass) {
    if($user) {
        $password = md5($pass);
        $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE ? = ?");
        if($this->_query->execute(array($pass, Check::data($user), $user))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}



class Check {
public static function data($data) {
    if($data) {
        if(is_numeric($data)) {
            $_id = 'id';
        } else if(filter_var($data, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $_id = 'email';
        } else {
            $_id = 'username';
        }
        return $_id;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: `WHERE ? = ?` <- here it is. You cannot bind to database identifiers (table / column names, etc)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table name as parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

Comment: it should be `WHERE column_name=?`

Comment: I know, so I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is intressed, I resolved the problem, and for future simular problems , I found a way around..

```
    public function change_password($user, $pass) {
    if($user) {
        $pass = md5($pass);
        $id = $this->id($user);

        $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE id = ?");
        if($this->_query->execute(array($pass, $id))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


    public function id($user) {
    if($user) {
        $params = $this->fetch($user);

        foreach($params as $param) {
            if($param['id']) {
                return $param['id'];
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

    public function fetch($user) {
    if($user) {
        if(Check::data($user) === 'id') {
            $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :user");
        }

        if(Check::data($user) === 'email') {
            $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :user");
        }

        if(Check::data($user) === 'username') {
            $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :user");
        }

        $this->_query->execute(array(':user' => $user));
        return $this->_query->fetchAll();           
    }
    return false;
}`class Check {
public static function data($data) {
    if($data) {
        if(is_numeric($data)) {
            $_id = 'id';
        } else if(filter_var($data, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $_id = 'email';
        } else {
            $_id = 'username';
        }
        return $_id;
    }
    return false;
} }
```